# Imprimir array para web server json

Tags: php, json, array

estoy creando un app en android utilizando webserver para obtener los datos a mostrar, quiero crear un api similar al siguiente resultado

```html
{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c202",
                "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
                "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c203",
                "name": "John Wayne",
                "email": "john_wayne@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c204",
                "name": "Angelina Jolie",
                "email": "angelina_jolie@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c205",
                "name": "Dido",
                "email": "dido@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c206",
                "name": "Adele",
                "email": "adele@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c207",
                "name": "Hugh Jackman",
                "email": "hugh_jackman@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c208",
                "name": "Will Smith",
                "email": "will_smith@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c209",
                "name": "Clint Eastwood",
                "email": "clint_eastwood@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2010",
                "name": "Barack Obama",
                "email": "barack_obama@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2011",
                "name": "Kate Winslet",
                "email": "kate_winslet@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2012",
                "name": "Eminem",
                "email": "eminem@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

tengo el sigguiente fragmento php

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM today";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // fetch data

// convert result to array
$resArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //$resArray[] = $row;
    $resArray[] = utf8_encode($row);
}

// display result
echo json_encode($resArray);
```

Comment: Bienvenido javiers, das muy poca información para poder ayudarte eficientemente, date una vuelta por el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) y en concreto por [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Seguro que si mejoras la pregunta recibirás una respuesta satisfactoria y que pueda ayudar a otros en una situación parecida.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Qué imprime la salida `echo json_encode($resArray);`? Si quieres estrictamente el JSON que presentas tienes que crearlo. Si la consulta no te arroja los datos como los esperas entonces tienes que construirla de forma distinta para que se adapte al JSON que espera Android. Y otra cosa, si usas GSon y clases que representen a tu modelo de datos te vas a ahorrar muchas líneas de código y podrás manejar / presentar la información con una facilidad asombrosa.